# How do I reuse a previously-opened port, using SBCL's sockets?

Tags: sockets, common-lisp, port, sbcl

Creating a server-side socket will fail if I'm trying to use the same port I've used before. An address-in-use error occurs.

```
(make-instance 'sb-bsd-sockets:inet-socket :type :stream :protocol :tcp)
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Hints and code snippets very welcome! (CL newbie here.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-REUSE-ADDRESS socket option accessor:

```
(setf (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-reuse-address socket) t)
```